# How to extract road line pattern from satellite images using Matlab?

Tags: image, matlab

Firstly we applied canny edge detection to the image, then detected lines using houghlines, then we got start and end points of the lines.

Then we applied delaunay triangulation and voronoi diagram for the points.

Now we need to get the skeleton of the pattern obtained.

What technique should be used?

I am implementing in Matlab.

Comment: Can you explain your steps a bit more detailed? Especially, why are you using a _Voronoi diagram_? This step is not clear to me, I guess you do it for some generalization / point reduction. Do you need to extract the Voronoi diagram lines _("skeleton")_? **Please edit your post and include the MATLAB code to generate the final output figure.** There are quite a variety of possibilities how to call [voronoi diagram functions in Matlab](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/voronoi.html), some of which return the vertices of the Veronoi edge lines:  `[vx, vy] = voronoi(x,y);`